# Programatic navigation for NavigationView using tag/selection or isActive

Tags: swiftui

`NavigationLink` has an initializer [`NavigationLink(destination:, tag:, selection:, label:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/3364637-init) that is supposed to be a hidden NavigationLink that gets active when selection == tag. Similiar to `NavigationLink(destination:isActive:label:)`.

Now I wondered, could I use this to have a property in a model that can be used to jump between pages arbitrarily? Aka, to support programatic navigation for NavigationView?

Something like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum NavStep {
    case step1
    case step2
}

class NavModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var step: NavStep? = .step1
}

struct Page1View: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var navModel: NavModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            // Hidden link from Page1 -> Page2 that gets active when model.step is set to .step2
            NavigationLink(destination: Page2View(), tag: NavStep.step2, selection: $navModel.step) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            Text("Page 1")
            Button("Go to Page 2") {
                self.navModel.step = .step2
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 1")
    }

}

struct Page2View: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var navModel: NavModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Page 2")
            Button("Go to Page 1") {
                self.navModel.step = .step1
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 2")
    }

}

struct ProgrammaticNavigationExample: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Page1View()
        }
        .environmentObject(NavModel())
    }

}

struct ProgrammaticNavigationExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgrammaticNavigationExample()
    }
}
```

Very well, works for two pages, you can navigate programatically by setting the step property.
But, now I wondered, how could this be extended to another, third page?

When I try to do this naively, setting 'model.step = .step3' breaks the navigation link in the first page and we're back to page 1. Even if I model this using two boolean properties 'enteredStep2' / 'enteredStep3' that could be set accordingly it gets flaky when trying to go back by setting these properties.

Any ideas how programmatic navigation could be enabled with this API (or in some other way)? Or any clue why NavigationView/NavigationLink behaves like it does for the examples?

Comment: [I would try to search at first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+NavigationLink+tag)

Comment: In short `NavigationLink` persists only for one step/level, think about this as like `NavigationView` has some `current` state, so all tags/isActive are valid only for one transition. On next stop all previous is replaced with current activated navigation link (no matter how interactively or programmatically). This behaviour was depicted in many posts for more than year of SwiftUI availability.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is currently not possible to use this API to build programatic navigation over multiple steps (see [Asperis comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920405/programatic-navigation-for-navigationview-using-tag-selection-or-isactive#comment109519536_61920405) for more information).

You can only use `NavigationLink(destination:, tag:, selection:, label:)` to make a programmatic decision on what View to show next, like:

```swift
struct ProgrammaticNavigationExampleView: View {

    enum NavDestination {
        case red
        case green
    }

    @State var destination : NavDestination?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            NavigationLink(destination: Color.red, tag: NavDestination.red, selection: $destination) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Color.green, tag: NavDestination.green, selection: $destination) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            Text("Page 1")
            Button("Show random page") {
                self.destination = [.red, .green].randomElement()!
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 1")
    }

}

struct ProgrammaticNavigationExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ProgrammaticNavigationExampleView()
        }
    }
}
```